# javaScript JSON localstorage, user input, only saving first entry

Tags: javascript, json

I am busy doing an online boot camp, and only recently started learning JavaScript, I was also introduced to JSON in this task, the task I am currently busy with, must take user input and store it in local storage, and also display it on the webpage. The user should also be able to edit or delete data already saved (I haven't even gotten to that part yet), I am just trying to get the data to store.
I finally got the input to display, but it is not storing it to the localStorage. I have googled a lot and followed online tutorials.
Any help or advice will be greatly appreciated. I have included my JS file below.

```
let entry = document.getElementById("entry");
entry.addEventListener("click", displayDetails);

let row = 1;

function displayDetails() {
  let title = document.getElementById("title").value;
  let artist = document.getElementById("artist").value;
  let album = document.getElementById("album").value;
  let genre = document.getElementById("genre").value;

  if (!title || !artist || !album || !genre) {
    alert("Please fill all boxes");
    return;
  }

  let display = document.getElementById("display");
  let newRow = display.insertRow(row);

  let cell1 = newRow.insertCell(0);
  let cell2 = newRow.insertCell(1);
  let cell3 = newRow.insertCell(2);
  let cell4 = newRow.insertCell(3);

  cell1.innerHTML = title;
  cell2.innerHTML = artist;
  cell3.innerHTML = album;
  cell4.innerHTML = genre;

  row++;
}

displayDetails = (ev) => {
  ev.preventDefault(); //to stop the form submitting
  let song = {
    title: document.getElementById("title").value,
    artist: document.getElementById("artist").value,
    album: document.getElementById("album").value,
    genre: document.getElementById("genre").value,
  }
  entry.push(entry);
  document.querySelector("form").reset();
  let pre = document.querySelector("#msg pre");
  pre.textContent = '\n' + JSON.stringify(entry, '\t', 2);
  localStorage.setItem("MySongList", JSON.stringify(entry));
}
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
});
```

Comment: `entry.push(entry);`? --- `entry` isn't an array. Also, do not  put DOM elements in local storage. Instead only keep data in local storage

Comment: entry.push(entry); why are you pushing entry.
declare an array outside function and push song object

Answer (score 0):

Declare songList array outside function and push the song object into songList and then save it as string into localStorage as given in the below code snippet.

```
let entry = document.getElementById("entry");
entry.addEventListener("click", displayDetails);

let row = 1;
const songList = [];

function displayDetails() {
  // your code......
  const song = {
    title: document.getElementById("title").value,
    artist: document.getElementById("artist").value,
    album: document.getElementById("album").value,
    genre: document.getElementById("genre").value,
  }
  songList.push(song);
  // your code......
  localStorage.setItem("MySongList", JSON.stringify(songList));
}
```

Comment: I'm not a fan of code-only answers.  Can you explain your answer with some supporting text?